# Shell STDIN redirection of three backticks

Tags: bash, stdin

## Motivation

I have a Markdown backtick codeblock and I would like to insert it into a list item.  I tried using awk with STDIN redirection for fun.  I ran into the following problem.

## Problem

I adapted from [Tutorials Point](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix/unix-io-redirections.htm)'s example to count the number of lines of a Markdown codeblock.

````
$ wc -l << EOF
```
codeblock
```
EOF
````

- Expected output: `3`
- Actual output:

  ```
  zsh: command not found: codeblock
  1
  ```

How to get the shell parse an odd number of backticks in STDIN?

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Backticks are for [command substitution](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_03), and command substitutions are expanded in [here documents](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_07_04). You should either quote `EOF` -this will disable all expansions-, or escape those backticks.

````
$ wc -l << 'EOF'
```
codeblock
```
EOF

3
$ 
$ wc -l << EOF 
\`\`\`
codeblock
\`\`\`
EOF

3
````

Comment: Thanks for answer.  I'll go for the 1st option for sure.